# jQuery validation for forms getting with foreach

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

```
<?php 
   foreach($matches as $match) {
        ?><form class="form-inline bet" method="POST" action="{{ url('/bet/process-team') }}">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="price" name="price" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $match->id; ?>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
  }
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".bet").validate({    
    rules: {
        price: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
        },
    }, 
});
```

With this validation even if I try to submit any form, the price input of the first form is required. I only require the price input of that form to be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a separate validator to each form - currently you're attaching a single validator to all the forms.

```
$('.bet').each( function(){
    var form = $(this);    // this is important, make the "form" local inside the function, otherwise $(this) changes scope each loop!
    form.validate({
        rules: {
            price: {
                required:true,
                number:true,
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**. You do not close your form tag in the foreach.

**Second**. Your class .bet is not unique so every form in the foreach will have the same class. Try making a function of your jquery. And call it with a unique id onsubmit

hope i understood your question correctly.